# Why does prefWidth in javafx takes an argument called height?

Tags: javafx

So I've been doing some work for my java class and noticed that Intellij IDEA gives me a warning I haven't seen before, when trying to set Pane's prefWidth. " 'WINDOW_WIDTH' should probably not be passed as parameter 'height' ". I didn't understanding this at first, but after some investigation I saw that Pane's prefWidth function takes an argument called height. And prefHeight takes an argument called width. Why is it like this? Did they accidentally mix up the names or is there something that I don't get?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what the documentation of [`Node#prefWidth(double)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#prefWidth(double)) says:

> Returns the node's preferred width for use in layout calculations. If the node is resizable, its parent should treat this value as the node's ideal width within its range. If the node is not resizable, just returns its layoutBounds width, which should be treated as the rigid width of the node.
>
> Layout code which calls this method should first check the content-bias of the node. If the node has a vertical content-bias, then callers should pass in a height value that the preferred width should be based on. If the node has either a horizontal or null content-bias, then the caller should pass in `-1`.
>
> Node subclasses with a vertical content-bias should honor the height parameter whether `-1` or a positive value. All other subclasses may ignore the height parameter (which will likely be `-1`).
>
> **Parameters:**
>   `height` - the height that should be used if preferred width depends on it
>
> **Returns:**
>   the preferred width that the node should be resized to during layout The result will never be NaN, nor will it ever be negative.

The documentation for the other width/height methods is similar. The above also mentions a content-bias which is handled by [`Node#getContentBias()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getContentBias()):

> Returns the orientation of a node's resizing bias for layout purposes. If the node type has no bias, returns null. If the node is resizable and it's height depends on its width, returns `HORIZONTAL`, else if its width depends on its height, returns `VERTICAL`.
>
> Resizable subclasses should override this method to return an appropriate value.
>
> **Returns:**
>   orientation of width/height dependency or null if there is none

You'll also want to look at the documentation of [`Node#isResizable()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#isResizable()) (for brevity, I'm not going to quote it here).

So the reason `Node#prefWidth(double)` takes a parameter named "height" is because the computation of the preferred width may depend on the height. For instance, the [`FlowPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html) layout overrides `getContentBias()` and has it return the same value as its [`orientation`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html#orientationProperty) property. When a `FlowPane` has an orientation of `VERTICAL` then the preferred *width* depends on the available height and if it has an orientation of `HORIZONTAL` then the preferred *height* depends on the available width.

Take note that there's a method for the minimum, preferred, and maximum width, same for the minimum, preferred, and maximum height:

- `Node#minWidth(double)` - parameter name is "height"
- `Node#minHeight(double)` - parameter name is "width"
- `Node#prefWidth(double)` - parameter name is "height"
- `Node#prefHeight(double)` - parameter name is "width"
- `Node#maxWidth(double)` - parameter name is "height"
- `Node#maxHeight(double)` - parameter name is "width"

***Note:** The above methods should probably not be called unless one is creating a layout. If you need the dimensions of a `Node` then look at its `boundsInLocal` or `boundsInParent` properties; if the `Node` is a `Region` it will also have read-only `width` and `height` properties.*

***Note:** The above methods are different from properties of `Region` (e.g. [`Region#prefWidthProperty()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#prefWidthProperty())).*